# How to populate selected dropdown text in angular 4

Tags: angular, typescript

I am using Angular 4 to get the country using select. For View and create page the dropdown working fine. But During update the selected dropdown text is not shown.

**client.ts**:

```
export class client {
 country: Country;
}
```

**client.html**:

```
    <select name="country" class="form-control m-input"  [(ngModel)]="client.country">
    <option *ngFor='let country of countrySource' [ngValue]="country">
    {{country.countryName}}
    </option>
    </select>
```

**component.ts**:

```
   import { client } from "./models/client";

    export class MyClientsComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {
           client = new client();

            getCountries() {
                    this._myclientsService.getCountry()
                        .subscribe(
                        res => this.onGetClientSuccess(res),
                        error => this.onGetClientFail(error));
                }
                onGetClientSuccess(res) {
                    this.countrySource = res.countries;
                }

                onGetClientFail(error) {
                    alert("error");
                }

    }
```

Comment: where you declare client object?

Comment: 'In my model i have client object. In view page the selected value is shown well. During Form updation the selected option is not populated to the country field'

Comment: you have bind client.country in ngModel so i am asking for  that object where you defined in your ts file

Comment: Please check my updated code

Comment: First declare in Oninit : clientDetails: client; and then put the following line in constructor and check : this.clientDetails = new client()

Comment: you have bind whole object to dropdown, bind one property of object to display.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem using compareWith directive to compare options to select.

sample.html

`<select [compareWith]="compareFn" name="country"  [(ngModel)]="client.country">
<option *ngFor='let country of countrySource' [ngValue]="country">                                      {{country.countryName}}
</option
</select>`

sample.ts

 `compareFn(c1: Country, c2: Country): boolean {
        return c1 && c2 ? c1.countryid === c2.countryid : c1 === c2;
    }`